# C# Checkbox: The name ... does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm having an issue with VS2010 C#:

I have created a Checkbox on my form named 'chkVehicles', in my Form1.cs I am trying to determine if the checkbox is checked, but I receive the error message:
"The name 'xVehicles' does not exist in the current context"

(My code works fine apart from the Checkbox...)

Form1.cs:

```
namespace plottingMap
{
    public partial class MapForm : Form
    {
        Map mapData = new Map();

        public MapForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            <..snip...>
        }

        <...snip...>

        private void chkVehicles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox xVehicles = (CheckBox)sender;
        }
}

class Map
{
    <...snip...>

    if (carpool.Contains(name) && xVehicles.Checked)
    {
        <...snip...>
    }
    <...snip...>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Please read up on scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `xVehicles` inside your `chkVehicles_CheckedChanged` event. You will not have access to it outside the method/event.

Not really sure why you need it outside the class, but if you have to,You can pass that as parameter to the calling method or to the class via constructor, or  define `xVehicles` at class level like:

```
public partial class MapForm : Form
    {
        Map mapData = new Map();
        public CheckBox xVehicles; //Like here

        public MapForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            <..snip...>
        }

        <...snip...>

        private void chkVehicles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xVehicles = (CheckBox)sender; //assign it the sender
        }
 //.....your rest of the code
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post, I have tried your suggestion but I still receive the same error message: "The name 'xVehicles' does not exist in the current context"

Just to make sure I added the code correctly:

`if (vehicleArray.Contains(objName) && xVehicle.checked)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass `xVehicles` as parameter to the method on class `Map`that is using it.

Another option is pass it on the contructor if that make sense. `Map` class can't see properties of your form.